# How do I make a textured mesh object grayscale in three.js?

Tags: canvas, three.js

I would like to make a textured object appear grayscale at the press of a button and then retain it's original color after the button is clicked again. How would I go about this?

Comment: Probably overkill but [you could use a 3D Lookup Table](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to solve this issue. Probably the easiest one is to prepare a second grayscale version of your texture. On button click, you just swap the textures.

An other option is to use a simple post-processing effect like in the following [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/239mjg4x/). However, this will change the visual appearance of the entire scene and not just of a single object. You need a more advanced post-processing like this [OutlineEffect](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline) if you want to manipulate only certain objects.

It's also possible to enhance an existing material so you can control with a uniform the conversion of the final color into a grayscale value. The uniform would be a simple integer value representing on/off.

```
// -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a texture image separated, you can also get canvas texture and recalculate new canvas as monochromatic, then replace model texture programatically:

// _c is original texture stored as canvas
var _canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var _ctx = _canvas.getContext("2d");
_ctx.canvas.width = _c.width;
_ctx.canvas.height = _c.height;

```
_ctx.drawImage(_c, 0, 0);

let imgData = _ctx.getImageData(0, 0, _c.width, _c.height);

// sandbox here, averange color is not true monochromatic, but its good enough for me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  let avg = (imgData.data[i + 0] + imgData.data[i + 1] + imgData.data[i + 2])/3;
  imgData.data[i + 0] = Math.min(avg+150,255);
  imgData.data[i + 1] = Math.min(avg+150,255);
  imgData.data[i + 2] = Math.min(avg+150,255);
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}
_ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

c.material.roughnessMap = new THREE.CanvasTexture(_canvas);
c.material.roughnessMap.flipY = false; // you need to unflip texture in some cases like GLTF models